# .net wcf webservice xml serialization - how to serialize object to a specific xml string

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization

I am doing a .net wcf webservice to output the following xml schema. (Following shema is just an example)

```
**<CarListOutput>
    <CarList>
      <Car>
        <Make />
        <Model /> 
        <Year />
      </Car>
      <Car>
        <Make />
        <Model /> 
        <Year />
      </Car>
    </CarList>
    <ExceptionList>
       <CustomError>
         <type />
         <errorMessage/>
       </CustomError>  
    </ExceptionList>      
</CarListOutput>**
```

I have my own class for "Car" (and also for "CustomError") and I have my return object "car list" (and also "CustomError list") ready with correct data. I can serialize this object to xml string or XElement seperately (car list and custom error list). My question is how can I convert the objects to the same as above xml? I want to do same as above xml since the client is expecting the specific xml (with the exact names). Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class CarListOutput with datamember CarList and exceptionList, let your operation contact return CarListOutput type object. For further control on CarListOutput XML format use XmlSerializerFormat. You can read more on XmlSerializer at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx